# can a string array go past 111?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to make an array that will gather all the lines in all the files in a directory, I thought I had it finally, but when the string array gets to entry 111 it crashes with an IndexOutOfRangeException

```
string[] WordList = new string[AdjectiveListLength];
Console.WriteLine("Length .. " + AdjectiveListLength);
Console.WriteLine("String Length .. " + WordList.Length);
int o = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < FileEntries.Length; i++)
{
    WordList = File.ReadAllLines(FileEntries[i]);
    foreach (string s in WordList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s + " .. " + i + " .. " + o);
        WordList[o] = s;
        //o += 1;
    }
}
```

The exception points to the int I commented out when I get the error, I've been trying to get this for a few hours and I've finally gotten this far I feel like I'm 1 inch from the finish line but I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: well, what's `AdjectiveListLength` defined to be? I'm guessing it's 110.

Comment: sorry I was trying to edit it just now to clarify, I made sure that it's the right length which is 582
http://i.imgur.com/hk0lmVC.png
here's an image showing it displaying using
            Console.WriteLine("Length .. " + AdjectiveListLength);
            Console.WriteLine("String Length .. " + WordList.Length);

Comment: Why use an array instead of a `List<string>`?

Comment: You are re-assigning `WordList` so it is no longer `AdjectiveListLength` in length: `WordList = File.ReadAllLines(FileEntries[i]);`. You probably just need to assign it to a temporary variable, iterate through the temporary, but still assign to the original through `WordList[o] = s;`.

Comment: I haven't been coding in c# very long (just a few weeks)  and I haven't begun learning Lists yet, I really wanted to stick to arrays but if it would save me here I'll go learn how to use them, thanks.
@Jace: I didn't know how to point out a line while making the question, it's only commented out on here, in my code it's not

Comment: Arrays are actually a more advanced concept. If you're just starting out, you might stay with List<T> collections for a little while, just to get your feet wet

Comment: @Quantic: the problem was me redefining the length, I don't know what compelled me to do that and miss it, thank you so much.  How on earth do I select the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for this task is to use a `List<string>` that could be used without knowing beforehand the length of each file in your FileEntries array

```
List<string> WordList = null;
for (int i = 0; i < FileEntries.Length; i++)
{
    WordList = File.ReadLines(FileEntries[i]).ToList();
    foreach (string s in WordList)
        Console.WriteLine(s + " .. " + i);

    // If you want also the line number then you could just use normal for..loop and C# 6.0 syntax
    for(int o = 0; o < WordList.Count(); o++)
        Console.WriteLine($"File:{i} at line {o} is ..{WordList[o]}");



}
```

If you really want to use arrays then you don't need to dimension the array because [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) already creates the array for you

```
string[] WordList = null;
for (int i = 0; i < FileEntries.Length; i++)
{
    WordList = File.ReadAllLines(FileEntries[i]);
    foreach (string s in WordList)
        Console.WriteLine(s + " .. " + i);
}
```